# Obtener y gráficar triangulo de Sierpinski

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Necesito ayuda con la generación de una secuencia a partir de

```
P = np.array([[0,0],
              [1,0],
              [0.5,np.sqrt(3)/2]])
```

`P` consta de tres entradas, cada una es un par ordenado que indica el vértice de un triángulo unitario

Con este triángulo necesito generar tres sub-triángulos, los vértices están en la lista `T` por eso obtengo una lista con 3^2 = 9 array. La cuestión es que quiero generar los siguientes sub-triángulos, lo que implica aplicar las mismas transformaciones a la nueva lista `T` para generar los nuevos 3^3 =27 vértices.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```
P = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0.5,np.sqrt(3)/2]])

m = []
for p in P:
    m.append(p*0.5)

n=[]
for p in P:
    n.append(p*0.5 + np.array([0.5,0]))

k=[]
for p in P:
    k.append(p*0.5 + np.array([0.25,np.sqrt(3)/4]))

T = np.array([m,n,k])
```

donde `T` es de la forma

```
T = [ 
    array([[0.,  0.], [0.5, 0.], [0.25, 0.4330127]]), 
    array([[0.5,  0.], [1, 0.], [0.75, 0.4330127]]), 
    array([[0.25, 0.4330127], [0.75, 0.4330127],[0.5, 0.8660254]]) ]
```

El objetivo es obtener el triángulo de Sierpinski y graficarlo utilizando la función de matplolib siguiente:

```
mpatches.Polygon(T[i], fc="y")
```

Saludos!

Comment: Seria bueno que dieras un poco más de contexto en tu pregunta. Porque no me queda claro si quieres una función recursiva o simplemente encontrar el array de 3^3.

Comment: Tienes razón, `P` consta de tres entradas, cada una es un par ordenado que indica el vértice de un triángulo unitario, a partir de este triángulo necesito generar tres sub-triángulos, los vértices están en la lista `T` por eso obtengo una lista con 3^2 = 9 `array`, la cuestión es que quiero generar los siguientes sub-triángulos, lo que implica aplicar las mismas transformaciones a la nueva lista `T` para generar los nuevos 3^3 =27 vértices. El objetivo es obter el triángulo de Sierpinski utilizando: `mpatches.Polygon(T[i], fc="y")`.

Comment: actualice la respuesta más acordé con tu comentario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finalmente logré conseguir una posible solución. La idea es que definas la etapa la cual desees observar el triangulo, por ejemplo, la **etapa 1** o mejor conocida como la [**trifuerza**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifuerza) se vería así:

[image: trifuerza]

Y así se vería la **etapa 5**:

[image: etapa 5]

En el código primero se definen los vertices del triangulo unitario y la etapa deseada. Luego con la función `get_triangle` obtienes un array de numpy que representa el triangulo de Sierpinski hasta la etapa que se definió. Finalmente para la gráfica se "remodela" el array para gráficar los triángulos obtenidos uno por uno.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

def get_triangle(P):
    m = P * 0.5
    n = P * 0.5 + np.array([0.5, 0])
    k = P * 0.5 + np.array([0.25, np.sqrt(3)/4])
    return np.array([m,n,k])

# triangulo unitario inicial
triangle = np.array([[0, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [0.5, np.sqrt(3)/2]])

# Crea un array que representa el triangulo Sierpinski hasta la etapa deseada
etapa = 5
for e in range(etapa):
    triangle = get_triangle(triangle)

# Se procede a graficar el triangulo
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for t in triangle.reshape(3**etapa,3,2):
    ax1.add_patch(mpatches.Polygon(t, fc="y"))

plt.show()
```

**Nota:** Por lo que he probado hasta ahora es una solución poco eficiente, pero te podría servir como base para lo que estas buscando. Al menos a mi me corre bien hasta la etapa 8. Tengo que investigar más para pulirla.

Comment: Gracias! Me será de mucha ayuda!